# Plotting KMF curve using lifelines in Pycharm exit code 0 but no output

Tags: python, matplotlib, lifelines

Sorry am quite new to this but I tried running some code and I get exit code 0 (no errors) but I do not see any output (in the Python console) 
Am using PyCharm Python 3.7 with lifelines package

```
from lifelines import KaplanMeierFitter

durations = [5,6,6,2.5,4,4]
event_observed = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

## create a kmf object
kmf = KaplanMeierFitter()

## Fit the data into the model
kmf.fit(durations, event_observed,label='Kaplan Meier Estimate')

## Create an estimate
kmf.plot(ci_show=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out! Needed `plt.show()`